# How to put 2-dimensional Array's pointer to the function as the parameter

Tags: c++, arrays, parameter-passing

I'm solving an algorithm problem using C++.

I want to put the pointer of 2-dimensional array that having different sizes of each dimension by init input dynamically.

What I coded as a function is below: the contents(the function of function) mean nothing.

```
int cal(int **arr){
int test = arr[0][0];
return 0;
}
```

And the result of this function

```
int arrayD[totalGroupCount][totalBeadCount];

int a = cal(arrayD);
```

It just says **"No Matching function call for 'cal'"**

I did declare the function 'cal'.

And I did it a lot with different symbol

```
int cal(int *arr[]){
int test = arr[0][0];
return 0;
}
```

But it says me identically.

I already searched for this question but answers I got make just the same error(I totally don't understand how they make it)

Comment: Note that type of `int arr[0][0]` is actually `int *` and not `int **`.

Comment: Please read up on multidimensional arrays, e.g. here: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/arrays/

Comment: Also note that `&arrayD` is *not* a `int**`.

Comment: @qarma: Err, what? The type of `int arr[x][y]` is `int[x][y]` not `int*`.

Comment: You want to use `int cal((arrayD*) [totalBeadCount]);`.

Comment: @qarma int arr[x][y] is not int *

Comment: @alk Thank you for your answer but totalBeadCount is dynamic integer value...

Comment: I think it's very difficult to solve more than I imagine

Comment: Then pass is a first parameter to the function: `int cal(size_t totalBeadCount, (arrayD*) [totalBeadCount]);`. This however is very Cish, C++ provides much more elegant ways to solve this.

Comment: `a = cal(&arrayD[0])` should compile. But this is not recommended anyway. In practice, casting a multidiensinal array to a pointer works only if the dimensions of the array are known except the first one. Since you have C++, use it, use stl!

Comment: @alk details, details, I'm saying what it's logically closer to

Answer (score 2):

As you use c++, there's better solution with `std::vector< vector<int > >`

```
int cal(std::vector<std::vector<int> > arr)
{
    int test = arr[0][0];
    return 0;
}
```

And call the function

```
std::vector<std::vector<int> >arrayD (totalGroupCount, std::vector<int>(totalBeadCount));
int a = cal(arrayD);
```

Also you can use `push_back()` function to dynamically add element to the vector.

Answer (score 0):

You need to allocate memory with `malloc`, `calloc`, or `new`:

```
long a;
int **pt; // a pointer to pointer to int
pt=new int*[rows]; // allocate memory for pointers,
// not for ints

for (a=0;a<rows;++a) pt[a]=new int[columns]; // here you're allocating
// memory for the actual data
```

This will create an array similar to `pt[rows][columns]`.

Then you pass `pt` like this:

```
int Func(int **data) {
//do something
return //something
}

Func(pt);
```

Comment: Is it the only answer? It's complicated and I don't understand why I should code like this way, not using basic way

Comment: @LKM, what way is _basic_?

Comment: @lkm It's not a basic way what you're doing, but actually a non standard c++ extension called variable length arrays.

Comment: Too many words. "Use `std::vector`" is all that's needed.

Comment: Why give a solution which ignores the prerequisite given by the OP, that is linear array, not a scattered one?

Comment: @alk, the OP just wants a 2D array and doesn't care about its placement in memory, does he?

Comment: @n.m., you're right, but the OP clearly says he wants a 2D array, not a vector, so I had to work with arrays as well

Comment: No, OP very clearly says nothing about vectors. Normally people want to solve problems, not to use specific library facilities.

Comment: From the OP: `int arrayD[totalGroupCount][totalBeadCount]; `